# OpenIddict 3 unavailable token validation from .NET 4.6

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openiddict

I have a Identity Server using OpenIddict 3.1. We have added a resource API with .NET 4.6. In the startup class, we are setting the token validation to use it on the `[Authorize]` attribute like this:

```
        var options = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(),
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = key(SigningCertificate from OpenIddict),
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidAudience = audience,
                RequireSignedTokens = true
            }
        };

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);
```

We always get the unauthorized message.

We also have tried to use:

```
        var options = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(),
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                IssuerSigningKeys = issuerSigningKeys,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidAudience = audience,
                RequireSignedTokens = true
            }
        };
```

On `issuerSigningKeys`, are the keys discovered from OpenIddict server JWT keys.

Our server configuration looks like this:

```
.AddValidation(options => {
                    options.UseLocalServer();
                    options.UseSystemNetHttp();
                    options.UseAspNetCore();
                });
```

and

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:49424/";
        options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:49424/";
        options.Audience = "resource1";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                            {
                                "resource1"
                            },
            IssuerSigningKey = (new RsaSecurityKey(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPublicKey(AuthenticationExtensionMethods.TokenSigningCertificate())))  // can still login with or without this key

        };
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Logon";
    });
```

Any suggestions? Is it possible to validate the tokens this way between different frameworks—such as .NET Core and .NET Framework 4.6—using OpenIddict?

Comment: What error do you get in the logs? You also need to separate authentication errors from authorization errors.

Comment: Hi Tore, we don't get any error, we have a custom Authorize Attribute and after the call base.SendGetAsync(request, canceltoken) we get the 401 Unauthorized message

Comment: do test by removing the authorize attribute, set a breakpoint in the action method and check if the User object contains a user or not. Just to separate if the issue is authentication (is the token accepted?) form authrorization (is the user allowed to access..)

Comment: feel free to paste a sample access token to the question as well.

Comment: Hi Toren, thanks a lot, we are not sure if it is an issue of the Authentication, because OpenIddict creates the access token and Id token, for front end it works fine, the issue it is when the frontend send an api request and the api request try to validate the token, the token that comes to the api it is Baerer token, but not an jwt token

Comment: what does the token look like? Feel free to post a sample token here. It could be that the token type you get back is a "reference token" an I don't think AddJwtBearer supports that.  can you not change the access token type in OpenIDDict? Have you set this feature? options.UseReferenceTokens();  if so, try to remove it. see https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/433

Comment: Hi Tore, you are right! it is solved!! also I added  options.DisableAccessTokenEncryption() because the token was not fine decrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OpenIDDict** supports two types of tokens: **reference** tokens (just a binary blogb) and **JWT-tokens** (contains user details and claims). The `AddJwtBearer()` method does not support the reference token format.

What you need to do is to remove the following line from your setup:

```cs
options.UseReferenceTokens();
```